# Long to short with data manipulation in r with 2 id pieces

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

In r a data set like below I want to create a variable that is prior minus post. I'll need to do some calculations by ID and later by group so I want to keep both.

Original

```
 ID   group      time    value   
 1      A        prior    8     
 1      A        post     5     
 2      A        prior    4     
 2      A        post     7     
 3      B        prior    3     
 3      B        post     10    
 4      B        prior    5
 4      B        post     6
```

Desired data

```
  ID      group   new_value     
  1         A        -3          
  2         A         3         
  3         B         7         
  4         B         1
```

I think to get there I need to make my data like this

```
 ID       group      value_prior      value_post
  1         A         8                  5
  2         A         4                  7
  3         B         3                  10
  4         B         5                  6
```

But I'm not sure how to get there while preserving ID and group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is already sorted, you could use:

```
aggregate(value ~ ID + group, df, diff)

  ID group value
1  1     A    -3
2  2     A     3
3  3     B     7
4  4     B     1
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, group) %>%
  summarise(new_value = diff(value))
```

Comment: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `output` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0

Comment: I suppose you have incomplete data for some cases?

Comment: I think it must be the same way I can't use the aggregate as a data frame. Sometimes the diff makes it a numeric(0) and it can't unlist without loosing values